# How do I float container to the left? [SUSY, Sass]

Tags: sass, susy-compass

is it possible to float a susy container to the left – instead of having it centered.

If yes, how do I do that? A regular float:left messes up the grid.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You don't need to float. The centering happens simply by setting `margin: auto` on both the right and left. Change either of those margins, and the container will move. In your case: just add any non-auto `margin-left`. The value you use will be the offset from the left edge.

```
// flush
@include container;
margin-left: 0;

// offset
@include container;
margin-left: 1em;
```